# Ionic admob implementation using floatinghotpot cordova-plugin-admob

Tags: android, cordova, admob, ionic-framework

I'm following this tutorial for having banner ads in my android application.
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

The problem is that I get an error callback from the plugin which is only telling me :

> Invalid action

I ran the cordova plugin add for the plugin, I modified the admob publisher id, I used the sample code from the tutorial right above but it always get stuck in the second callback function which is the error case callback.

Here is the code I used :

```
var admobApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
                var admob_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ANDROID_PUBLISHER_KEY" : "IOS_PUBLISHER_KEY";
                var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
                admob.createBannerView( 
                    {
                        'publisherId': admob_key,
                        'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                        'bannerAtTop': false
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        admob.requestAd(
                            { 'isTesting': false }, 
                            function() {
                                admob.showAd(true);
                            }, 
                            function() { console.log('failed to request ad'); }
                        );
                    }, 
                    function() { console.log('failed to create banner view'); }
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: On your Android log you should be able to see the action that is _Invalid action_. Also could you be a little more specific about which call gives this error and how do you gather it as your code has no option for that. Is it the _requestAd_ or _showAd_ call that throws the error?

Comment: It's the call to the "createBannerView" function which is causing this error. It's then going to the error callback method which contains the console.log 'failed to create ....'. I got that information by adding a parameter to the second callback function (the one displaying a log error message), it's value is a string containing "Invalid action". So it doesn't even call the request or show ad function because it's the main function call (to "createBannerView" which is calling back the error function with an error string "Invalid action"...)

Comment: with the new plugin release the APi has changed so make sure you are using the "pro" plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro here is a tutorial for that http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-banner-ads-to-ionic-apps-using-admob-pro-plugin/